# How can I fix "atomic" related issues in my build?

Tags: raspbian, bash, script, gcc, make

I'm trying to build gRPC using this tutorial (https://lzqblog.top/2018-11-08/Cross-compile-gRPC-for-ARM/) but I still get "atomic" related issues (undefined reference: __atomic_fetch_add_8 )...

Note: I'm building on a raspberry running raspbian. Oh, and I'm no Linux expert...

Can anyone help me?

Terminal :

```
pi@extractor:~/grpc/grpc $ make -j2 && sudo make install -j2 && sudo ldconfig
[MAKE]    Generating cache.mk
[HOSTLD]  Linking /home/pi/grpc/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_cpp_plugin
[HOSTLD]  Linking /home/pi/grpc/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_csharp_plugin
/usr/bin/ld: /home/pi/grpc/grpc/libs/opt/protobuf/libprotobuf.a(arena.o): in function `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::Init()':
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/atomic_base.h:514: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4283: /home/pi/grpc/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_cpp_plugin] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/usr/bin/ld: /home/pi/grpc/grpc/libs/opt/protobuf/libprotobuf.a(arena.o): in function `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaImpl::Init()':
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/atomic_base.h:514: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4316: /home/pi/grpc/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_csharp_plugin] Error 1
pi@extractor:~/grpc/grpc $
```

Error : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work! :)

I'm no Linux expert and I made plenty of tests (trial & errors) so here are some notes that might help the next person who has this problem:

- The app I was needing the grpc for is built in .Net Core 3.1 and was deployed/debugged remotely via ssh from Windows 10 (using Visual Studio 2019).
- I built the grpc "v1.34.0-pre1" release on Raspbian 10 having GCC 5.5.0 installed.
- I needed the "libgrpc_csharp_ext.so" file for firestore (renamed to libgrpc_csharp_ext.x86.so); I just added it to published path (not replacing a file).
- I red about "-latomic" but did'nt have to use it.

Here are the links that helped me make it work:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.33.2/BUILDING.md#pre-requisites
- https://github.com/erikest/libgrpc_csharp_ext
- https://lzqblog.top/2018-11-08/Cross-compile-gRPC-for-ARM/

And maybe:

- https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libatomic-ops-dev
- https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-raspbian

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as an unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.